# MySQL (DEFAULT + ON UPDATE) TIMESTAMPs

Tags: mysql, database, types, timestamp

I've a table where I've two fields:

```
dateCreated
dateUpdated
```

I want both fields to hold timestamps, dateCreated to have a DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP flag and dateUpdated to have a ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP behavior, however seems that I can't have more than one timestamps field types on the same table.

It would be really useful if the database could take care of this for me, can I circumvent this issue somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES WE CAN.

You can use a [`trigger`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to update the field, like so:

```
create trigger CreationTimestamp after insert on MyTable for each row
begin
    update MyTable set CreateField = UpdateField where id = new.id
end
```

This way, you can set your auto-update field using the native MySQL method, and use this to capture the creation date.