# How to create 2 auto-set timestamp columns in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I want a MySQL table of mine to contain 2 timestamp columns, both set automatically without the client side help: one to be initialized once on insert:

```
`added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and another initialized the same on insert and updated on every update:

```
`updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

But this doesn't work this way:

> [Err] 1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

Is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not just a workaround, there is a solution: Upgrade to MySQL 5.6.5 or higher and this is supported.

See: [MySQL 5.6.6 TIMESTAMP columns and DEFAULT values](http://shankargopal.blogspot.in/2013/03/mysql-566-timestamp-columns-and-default.html)

{edit} Since upgrading is not an option, you can make the first column a normal timestamp column and create a trigger that sets one timestamp when you insert the record. Then you can create the other colum with the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so it gets a timestamp on insertion and on update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER task_creation_timestamp BEFORE INSERT ON tasks 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.created = NOW();
```

I've stolen this trigger from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907139/511529).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately there is no chance I convince my shared hosting provider to update anything until they come to this idea themselves. I upvote your answer anyway.

Comment: You can use a trigger as well. I've just added that suggestion to my answer, but for an example, you might check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906978/mysql-how-to-create-trigger-for-setting-creation-date-for-new-rows).

Answer (score 1):

There is no "solution" as the error suggest, you can ONLY HAVE ONE TIMESTAMP per table (On previous versions of 5.6.6 as [GolezTrol Suggested](http://shankargopal.blogspot.in/2013/03/mysql-566-timestamp-columns-and-default.html))

To workaround this i suggest you make of the "timestamps" a `datetime` and set the default to `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` or [any other synonym for `NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: The same `TIMESTAMP` data type seems to work just fine so I can see no reason to use `DATETIME` here (yes, I like `DATETIME` better normally but as far as we have use `TIMESTAMP` already it seems preferable to keep with it just to avoid complications).